# How to fix CORS Error using Livewire Stripe Prebuilt Checkout

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-livewire

I'm using a simple [Stripe Prebuilt Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/quickstart) (HTML/PHP) within a Livewire component.

It works fine on local but not in production.

When I view the Network I see I get a `Status: CORS Error` then a `Status: 403 error`.

See image:
[image]

**Here is my code:**

Component:

```
<form wire:submit.prevent="checkout">
    <x-assets.checkout-button type="submit" id="checkout-button">
        Buy Now
    </x-assets.checkout-button>
</form>
@push('stripe')
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?version=3.52.1&features=fetch"></script>
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
@endpush
```

Then in the Server Side:

```
    public function checkout()
    {
        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(config('services.stripe.secret'));

        header('Content-Type: application/json');

        $YOUR_DOMAIN      = config('app.url');
        $checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
            'billing_address_collection'  => 'required',
            'shipping_address_collection' => [
                'allowed_countries' => ['US'],
            ],
            'line_items' => [[
                // Provide the exact Price ID (e.g. pr_1234) of the product you want to sell
                'price'    => $this->product->stripe_plan,
                'quantity' => 1,
            ]],
            'mode' => 'payment',
            'allow_promotion_codes' => true,
            'success_url'   => url($YOUR_DOMAIN . '/product/thank-you'),
            'cancel_url'    => $YOUR_DOMAIN . '/product',
            'automatic_tax' => [
                'enabled' => false,
            ],
        ]);

        header('HTTP/1.1 303 See Other');
        header('Location: ' . $checkout_session->url);

        return redirect($checkout_session->url);
    }
```

These are the directions I'm following: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/quickstart

I have a form element and I'm not using `@CSRF` because I'm using Livewire.

In my VerifyCsrfToken.php file I have the following for Livewire:

```
    protected $except = [
        'stripe/webhook',
        'shippo/webhook',
        'discord/webhook',
        'livewire/*',
    ];
```

Is it something to do with the Headers in the Server side code? `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot send a redirect response to a `fetch` / `XMLHttpRequest`. You need to either change your client request pattern (eg, a form submit), or send the session `url` back to the client as data and redirect client-side instead.

See this previous answer for an example of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68630525

Comment: If you know a question is a duplicate, please flag it for closure as such instead of answering.

Comment: Yea good call. I debated it, but wasn't sure about the similarities/differences/complexities in handling the fetch via "livewire" as I'm not familiar with it.